# parsing CSV file with delayed job issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, delayed-job

I have a CSV file to parse with two ways:

1. Upload the file and parse it in real time
2. Upload the file and parse it with a delayed_job

When I parse the file in real time, there is no problem, but when I parse the file with a delayed job, I get a CSV::Table but with nil fields [nil,nil.....]

This is how I parse the file in the helper:

```
CSV.parse(file.read, :headers => true, :row_sep =>:auto)
```

This is how I save the csv file and I create the delayed job:
yeah its CSV, I made a typo, but I still have the problem, I read the file in an action like this:

```
def create
if  params[:dump]
  file = File.new(params[:dump][:file].original_filename, "w")
  File.open(file.path, "w") { |f| f.write(params[:dump][:file].read.force_encoding('UTF-8')) }

  @import = Import.create(:created_by => current_user.id, :import_file_path => file.path, :size => 0)
  file.close
  file_to_parse = File.open(@import.import_file_path)
  if params[:dump][:file].size <  10000
    parsed_file = parsed file_to_parse
    if parsed_file &&  parsed_file.count > 0
      @imported_contacts, @imported_organizations = extract_contacts_and_organizations_from parsed_file

      validate_and_save @imported_organizations if @imported_organizations.any?
      validate_and_save @imported_contacts      if @imported_contacts.any?

      @import.update_attributes(:done => true, :size => (@imported_contacts.size + @imported_organizations.size))

      redirect_to org_import_path(current_org, @import)
    else
      redirect_to new_org_import_path(current_org) , :notice => "fichier vide ou introuvable ou ne pas de format cvs/vcf"
    end
  else
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(ImportJob.new(current_org, current_user, @import.id))
    redirect_to org_import_path(current_org, @import)
  end
else
  redirect_to new_org_import_path(current_org) , :notice => "vous devrez selctionner un fichier"
end

end
```

Comment: I think you have confused CVS and CSV. Judging from the arguments you are passing, I think you mean CSV. CVS is a source management system

Comment: A more detailed example of code would help/ i.e. where you read in the file, where you call the delayed job etc.

Comment: yeah its CSV , I made a typo , but i still have the problem, i read the file in an action like this

Comment: I added in the question how i upload the file and how I create the job delayed, thnaks for the help, really i can't find a solution, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Where is the code for the ImportJob? We need to see how it runs the parsing to see what the differences are.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `@import` object has the `:import_file_path` variable that points to a tempfile (file.path) uploaded by a user.
Since this tempfile will be automatically removed as soon as the action finishes, the delayed job can't find the file when it attempts to run the job in the background (the action is already finished).

What about to copy a tempfile to some place and use it instead?
In this case, you need to add a line of code that deletes the copied file at the end of the delayed job process.

I hope this works for your problem.